# Expire the JWT Token on logout in Spring Boot REST API

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jwt

How can I invalidate the JWT token when a user clicks the logout button? I have done some research but I was not able to find any good implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You were not able to find any way to "expire" `JWT` because there is no such way. We can say it's a drawback of `JWT`.

If the `token` is compromised, then it's a huge problem. You might want to consider other auth mechanism if you need to invalidate tokens/sessions.

The only way to "invalidate" such a token would be to use other `secret` key on backend - which is obviously an exceptionally horrible idea!

However, if you are looking for a way to "log out" user on frontend, simply clear the JWT from the storage. (Still, if that user copied the token, he will be able to execute requests against rest api).

Comment: Can you suggest any good  auth mechanism to implement with spring boot rest api which will allow to invalided and refresh token properties.

Comment: It's a very broad topic and needs discussion/consideration against requirements. There are many mechanisms and each of them has their pros and cons. Sessions, basic auth, OAuth, JWT and so forth and so on. You would need to read about each of them and  then, after gathering some knowledge, decide.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. There are ways and they are really simple, check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to just have a bannedUsers table. You could possibly even cache this table. If a users account ever becomes compromised, you can just add them to the table until their token expires. It would be a lookup everytime (unless cached), but there would most likely always be 0 records on the table so it would be very fast.

Answer (score 2):

On the same line as @RonOhRob I would suggest the [`jti` (JWT ID)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim. This claim provides a unique identifier for the JWT.

Your JWT payload would look like:

```js
{
    "iss": "example.com",
    "iat": "1300819080",
    "exp": "1300819380",
    "jti": "123e4567-e89b-42d3-a456-556642440000",
    "username": "mneri"
}
```

When a JWT is manually expired you insert the `jti` into a blacklist. The value should persist into the table until the natural expiration of the token. Now, for each request should also check if `jti` inside the table; if it's found the access is denied.

If a user wants to expire all of his tokens there's another simple strategy involving the [`iat` (Issued At)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.6) claim: add a `deny_before` field to the `user` table and register the date of the `expire_all` API call. As before, you have to add a check to each request.

For a complete reference on how to integrate JWT into Spring take a look at [JavaBrain's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X80nJ5T7YpE).
The guy in the video is using `jjwt`, but i'd reccomend [auth0's java-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt) library, that to my taste offers a better interface:

```java
JWT.create()
   .withJWTId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
   .withIssuer(ISSUER)
   .withIssuedAt(issueDate)
   .withExpiresAt(expireDate)
   .withClaim("username", user.getUsername())
   .sign(Algorithm.HMAC256("secret"));
```

Now, inside your `JWTFilter`:

```java
JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(ALGORITHM).withIssuer(ISSUER).build();
DecodedJWT decoded = verifier.verify(jwt);

if (blacklistService.find(jwt.getId())) {
    throw new JWTVerificationException();
}

User user = userService.loadByUsername(jwt.getClaim("username").asString());

if (user.getDenyBefore() != null && user.getDenyBefore().compareTo(jwt.getIssuedAt()) > 0) {
    throw new JWTValidationException();
}
```

Comment: Well, it does not make the token itself invalid. It's a blacklist. This is a different thing. Of course it can be a solution in some cases but this is not invalidation per se.